# LINQ query not taking String as the value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

Is possible to write a query like below using LINQ? Is giving me the error

> "cannot be applied to operands of type double and string"

```
key = Request.QueryString["key"];

var query = from p in db.VERSIONs where p.vr_key == key select p;
```

Comment: You should give us more code, but I guess that `p.vr_key` is of type double like your message says.

Comment: You need to parse to string the verkey

Comment: @LinusCalwell, how can I do that?

Comment: @Ravi, How can I parse to string the vr_key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
Double key = Convert.ToDouble(Request.QueryString["key"]);

var query = from p in db.VERSIONs where p.vr_key == key select p;
```

Comment: Dang.  Every time I bust out VS2010 to test a workable solution, someone else beats me to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use TryParse method to make sure your string is compatible/ convertible because query string can be anything. Otherwise a user can easily break your code simply typing something for key.

```
double key;
if(Double.TryParse(Request.QueryString["key"], out key))
{
    var query = from p in db.VERSIONs 
                        where p.vr_key == key 
                        select p;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the even better solution. Parsing a `QueryString` without checking is risky.

Comment: It's only risky if you don't know whether or not the string you're parsing is the type you're looking for.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: user can type anything on address bar and enter. ex : www.yoursite.com?key=hello

Answer (score -1):

Use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) to convert `p.vr_key`.

Try this:

```
key = Request.QueryString["key"];

var query = from p in db.VERSIONs where SqlFunctions.StringConvert(p.vr_key) == key select p;
```

Comment: I did not give you the downvote but I'm assuming it's because you converted the database value to a string rather than parsing the key value to a double to match the database type